# Share a matrix among processes in starmap in python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have the function `parallel_l21` that I want to parallelize. The problem is that it seems that `W_hat` is not shared among different processes. How do I make `W_hat` sharable among processes?

```
def parallel_l21(labels, X, W_hat, lam, g):
    print(g)
    g_indxs = np.where(schaefer_labels == g)[0]
    tmp = rfs(X[g_indxs, 1:].T, X[:, :-1].T, gamma=lam, verbose=False).T
    tmp[abs(tmp) <= 1e-6] = 0
    W_hat[:, g_indxs] = tmp

 with Pool(processes=12) as pool:
     print(pool)
     pool.starmap(parallel_l21, zip(repeat(labels), repeat(X), W_hat, repeat(lam), np.unique(labels)))
```

Comment: using `repeat` without passing a `n` parameter means it will endlessly generate a value. Since `starmap` unpacks the iterables passed to it will forever be unpacking the `repeat` generators before it even starts to run your function

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe `np.unique(labels)` has a fixed size so this will stop `repeat` generator. The problem was I missed `zip` function. The post has a one question now.

Comment: a fixed size array has no effect on stopping `repeat` per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)